# Why can't EF Core 3.1 not able to determine the relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

Earlier I had the following classes with relationship

```cs
    [Table("User")]
    public class User
    {
        // Base properties
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // Relationships
        public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("UserRole")]
    public class UserRole
    {
        // Base properties
        [Key]
        public int UserRoleId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // Relationships
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public User User { get; set; }
    }
```

EF Core was able to map this to SQL as intended which gave two tables

1. User - UserId (PK), Name
2. UserRole - UserRoleId (PK), Name, UserId (FK)

Later I wanted to add a way to verify the records and the verifiers are coming from the User table itself. The below is how the verification implemented:

```cs
    [Table("User")]
    public class User
    {
        // Base properties
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // Relationships
        public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

        // Verification
        public int? VerifierId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("VerifierId")]
        public User Verifier { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("UserRole")]
    public class UserRole
    {
        // Base properties
        [Key]
        public int UserRoleId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // Relationships
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public User User { get; set; }

        // Verification
        public int? VerifierId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("VerifierId")]
        public User Verifier { get; set; }
    }
```

The above setup is giving the following exception while adding the migration: `Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'User.UserRoles' of type 'ICollection<UserRole>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.`

However removing the below property in the UserRole table makes the migration possible:

```cs
ForeignKey("VerifierId")]
public User Verifier { get; set; }
```

But it is not what I want. I want the foreign key kept as well. How to make this possible? and why this is not allowed at the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that EF does not know which FK (`UserId` or `VerifierId`) should be mapped to the `UserRoles` property of the `User` class.

You need to define which foreign key should be used

```
[InverseProperty(nameof(UserRole.User))]
public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
```

See the documentation here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships